# 40 amp Pool heater hooked up to 60 amp outdoor Spa Box

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I purchased a Siemens electric panel for a spa with a 60 amp breaker. Is there any danger in hooking up my 40 Amp pool water heater to it?

2nd Question...The Panel comes with 4 slots, can i use the 60 amp GFCI Breaker in the house and use regular non GFCI 40 amp + 15 amp Breakers in the box (15 amp Breaker is for the pool pump)

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please ask one question per post.

Comment: For the first question, is all the wiring after the 60a breaker sized for 60a, or is there any wire sized for 40a?

Comment: Is the wire from the panel to the hot tub #6 copper or fatter (lower numerically)?  If aluminum #4 or fatter.

Comment: Yes the wiring is conform to the needs of 60 amps the box is located about 100 feet from the main panel, the wire is well over an inch thick

Comment: Is the breaker panel in the house also a Siemens of the same family, i.e. does its labeling permit use of that model of 60A breaker?

Comment: Yes i have a Siemens Main Panel in the house, everything is made by Siemens

Answer (score 3):

Double check everything, since Siemens makes several lines of breaker/panel (which are physically incompatible so they plainly won't fit), but it all makes sense to me.

- You made a canny choice of hot tub subpanel so you could swap breakers - smart economics.
- The farther upstream the GFCI protection is, the better - and you can't get more upstream than the main panel, can you? :)
- The breaker in the panel is able to protect the #6 cable and 60A subpanel.
- The breaker has the correct thresholds for a hot tub (8ma and not 30ma) since it's *sold as a hot tub panel*.
- With the subpanel fully GFCI protected, you can put plain breakers in there.  *Though a typical dumb home inspector isn't going to like it.*

Be sure to put "GFCI Protected" labels on the receptacles and subpanel, I recommend making your own with a common labelmaker, as they last longer than the blue paper ones that come with GFCIs.

Comment: I agree mostly, having 120 circuits inside on a 240 protected GFCI may cause neucence tripping in my experiance,  but the heater will be protected.